# Erlang list comprehension with two lists in sequence?

Tags: erlang, binary, list-comprehension

Is it possible to use list comprehension on two lists, item by item, in sequence? Given `A = [1,2,3]`, `B = [4,5,6]`, get some `C = [f(1, 4), f(2, 5), f(3, 6)]`. In other words, a more direct/efficient way to do `[f(U, V) || {U, V} = lists:zip(A, B)].`

Similar question goes to binaries, if given `A = <<1,2,3>>` and `B = <<4,5,6>>`. This would be very useful if you have to xor two binaries, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not currently possible. It has already been proposed in [EEP12](http://www.erlang.org/erlang-enhancement-proposals/eep-0012.html) and [EEP19](http://www.erlang.org/erlang-enhancement-proposals/eep-0019.html).

Your best choice is to implement your own recursive function for that.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a higher-order-function in the `lists` module for this and it is called [lists:zipwith/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#zipwith-3). Your example scenario would be implemented this way:

```
lists:zipwith(fun f/2, A, B).
```

Comment: Yes, there are functions for zipping two or three lists. But there is no general solution for N lists, as a list comprehension would be.